# why am I getting this error meassage when trying to sign up on Area 51 with OpenID account?

Tags: bug, area-51, login

I am trying to make an account by clicking the OpenID button on Area 51 site. I get this instead:
[image: error]
why?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @rene I am using Chrome

Comment: And no other plugins/add-ons that might be at play?

Comment: @rene extensions: disconnect, Blur, privacy badger

Comment: Ah, are any of those preventing or intercepting third-party cookies?

Comment: yep, all of them

Comment: That might be the problem then. The login system seems to rely on browsers accepting 3rd party cookies. But I think it is better to wait for @AdamLear to confirm or dismiss my guesses

Comment: @rene how come it doesn't work with only Area 51 though?

Comment: That is because Area51 is an older/different code base that is not/ not easily patched for newer features.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/987/discussion-between-flipfloop-and-rene).